# Обратимое шифрование лицензионного ключа

Tags: c#, криптография

Имеется алгоритм, с помощью которого генерируются лицензионные ключи, для offline активации программ. Это означает, что информация о лицензии закодирована непосредственно в ключе. Для генерации лицензионного ключа используется имя и версия программы, а также имя владельца лицензии. Почти весь код был собран из разных источников в интернете и несколько адаптирован под мою задачу. Как и что я делаю:

#### Генерация ключа лицензии

1. Создаю "соль" используя имя и версию программы;
2. В качестве пароля для расшифровки лицензионного ключа используется имя владельца лицензии;
3. Создаю [Rijndale](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndael?view=netframework-4.7.1) используя ранее созданную "соль" и как пароль - владельца лицензии;
4. Зашифровываю информацию о лицензии в закодированный массив байтов;
5. Преобразую полученный массив байтов с помощью [BASE36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) в удобочитаемый вид;

#### Расшифровка лицензии

1. На стороне программы с помощью рефлексии получаю имя и версию программы, а также владельца лицензии;
2. На основании полученной информации формирую "соль" и пароль;
3. Получаю из лицензионного ключа в формате [BASE36](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base36) обратно массив закодированных байтов;
4. Создаю [Rijndale](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rijndael?view=netframework-4.7.1) используя ранее созданную "соль" и пароль;
5. Расшифровываю массив закодированных байтов обратно в информацию о лицензии;

Проблема в том, что я могу зашифровать с таким подходом только строки длинной от 16 до 31 символа. Как можно модифицировать существующий код для строк различной длинны?

P.S.: "поиграться" с кодом можно [здесь](https://repl.it/@XelaNimed/SimpleLicInfo).

#### Класс BASE36

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public static class BASE36
    {
        private const string _charList = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        private static readonly char[] _charArray = _charList.ToCharArray();

        public static long Decode(string input)
        {
            long _result = 0;
            double _pow = 0;
            for (int _i = input.Length - 1; _i >= 0; _i--)
            {
                char _c = input[_i];
                int pos = _charList.IndexOf(_c);
                if (pos > -1)
                {
                    _result += pos * (long)Math.Pow(_charList.Length, _pow);
                }
                else
                {
                    return -1;
                }

                _pow++;
            }
            return _result;
        }

        public static string Encode(ulong input)
        {
            var _sb = new StringBuilder();
            do
            {
                _sb.Append(_charArray[input % (ulong)_charList.Length]);
                input /= (ulong)_charList.Length;
            } while (input != 0);

            return Reverse(_sb.ToString());
        }

        private static string Reverse(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Класс Program

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string saltString = GetSaltString("Blechexport", "15");
            byte[] salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(saltString);
            string pwd = "J.Doe";
            string licInfo = $"[0,{new DateTime(2019, 11, 30).Ticks},10]";
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(licInfo);
            var seconds = new DateTime(2019, 12, 31).Ticks / 10000000;
            string[] testDatas = new string[]{
                $"[0,{seconds},1]",
                $"[1,{seconds},10]",
                $"[2,{seconds},10,10]",
                $"[3,{seconds},10,10,10]",
                $"[3,{seconds},10,10,10,10]",
                $"[3,{seconds},10,10,10,10,10]"
                // throws System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
                // ,$"[3,{seconds},10,10,10,10,10,10]"
            };
            foreach (string testData in testDatas)
            {
                TestLic(pwd, salt, testData);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void TestLic(string pwd, byte[] salt, string phrase)
        {
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(phrase);
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine($"phrase: {phrase} ({phrase.Length} symbols)");
            string licKey;
            using (var rijndael = InitSymmetric(Rijndael.Create(), pwd, salt, 256))
            {
                byte[] encryptedBytes = Transform(bytes, rijndael.CreateEncryptor);
                licKey = GenerateUID(encryptedBytes);
                Console.WriteLine($"encrypted bytes: {BitConverter.ToString(encryptedBytes)}");
                Console.WriteLine($"license key: {licKey}");
                Console.WriteLine($"key length: {licKey.Length}");
            }

            using (var rijndael = InitSymmetric(Rijndael.Create(), pwd, salt, 256))
            {
                byte[] uidBytes = GetUIDInBytes(licKey);
                byte[] decryptedBytes = Transform(uidBytes, rijndael.CreateDecryptor);
                Console.WriteLine($"decrypted bytes: {BitConverter.ToString(decryptedBytes)}");
                string decryptedText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
                Console.WriteLine("decryptedText: {0}", decryptedText);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------");
        }

        static string GetSaltString(string programmName, string programmVersion)
        {
            return $"{programmName}.{programmVersion}";
        }

        static string GenerateUID(byte[] bytes)
        {
            //Convert checksum into 4 ulong parts and use BASE36 to encode both
            string _part1Id = BASE36.Encode(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 0));
            string _part2Id = BASE36.Encode(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8));
            string _part3Id = BASE36.Encode(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 16));
            string _part4Id = BASE36.Encode(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 24));
            //Concat these 4 part into one string
            return string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}-{3}", _part1Id, _part2Id, _part3Id, _part4Id);
        }

        static byte[] GetUIDInBytes(string UID)
        {
            //Split 4 part Id into 4 ulong
            string[] _ids = UID.Split('-');
            //Combine 4 part Id into one byte array
            byte[] _value = new byte[32];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BASE36.Decode(_ids[0])), 0, _value, 0, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BASE36.Decode(_ids[1])), 0, _value, 8, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BASE36.Decode(_ids[2])), 0, _value, 16, 8);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BASE36.Decode(_ids[3])), 0, _value, 24, 8);
            return _value;
        }

        static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(plainText));
            }
            if (Key == null || Key.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Key));
            }
            if (IV == null || IV.Length == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(IV));
            }
            byte[] encrypted;
            // Create an AesManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }

                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }
            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }

        static string DecryptStringFromBytes_Aes(byte[] cipherText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (cipherText == null || cipherText.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipherText));
            }
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Key));
            }
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(IV));
            }
            // Declare the string used to hold
            // the decrypted text.
            string plaintext = null;
            // Create an AesManaged object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (AesManaged aesAlg = new AesManaged())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                // Create a decryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
                // Create the streams used for decryption.
                using (MemoryStream msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipherText))
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                        {
                            // Read the decrypted bytes from the decrypting stream
                            // and place them in a string.
                            plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }

        static SymmetricAlgorithm InitSymmetric(SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm, string password, byte[] salt, int keyBitLength)
        {
            const int Iterations = 234;
            using (var rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, Iterations))
            {
                if (!algorithm.ValidKeySize(keyBitLength))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid size key");
                }
                algorithm.Key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(keyBitLength / 8);
                algorithm.IV = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(algorithm.BlockSize / 8);
                return algorithm;
            }
        }

        static byte[] Transform(byte[] bytes, Func<ICryptoTransform> selectCryptoTransform)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, selectCryptoTransform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                }
                return memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам обратимое шифрование? Что вы хотите достать из лицензии?

Comment: я не спец совсем, но что если взять рандомную строку, добить её пробелами до нужной длины, поделить на блоки по 16 или 31 и зашифровать каждый блок отдельно?

Comment: в каком месте возникает проблема при попытке зашифровать что то меньше 16 или больше 31 символа?

Comment: @Zergatul в методе Transform `cryptoStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);`

Comment: @tym32167 если я правильно понял, что ты имеешь ввиду, то в этом случае ключ разрастётся, т.е. при длине кодируемой информации в 31 символ - длина ключа ~53, а при длине информации в 32 символа - уже ~100 символов.

Comment: @XelaNimed а какая конкретно проблема? CryptoStream поддерживает любую длину входящих данных для шифрования

Comment: почему 100? Раз ты можешь по 16 символов кодировать, то длина должна быть кратной 16. То есть для 32 символоа делать не надо ничего, просто делишь на 2 куска по 16. Для 33 символов - добивешь пробелы до 48

Comment: поогоди, так ты сам себе ограничение в 32 символа придумал? Я в [доке](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.write?view=netframework-4.8) ничего такоо не вижу

Comment: вот это `byte[] _value = new byte[32];` походу тебя ограничивает, но это твой код

Comment: У вас странный подход. Вам не нужно расшифровывать ключ. Вам нужно, не обратимое шифрование (хеширование), а в программе не расшифровывать, а наоборот, проделать все те же действия, что на сервере, зашифровать своё имя и сверить с хешом. Хеширование без проблем настраивается на выдачу результата нужной вам длины, вне зависимости от входных данных. Другими словами лицензионный ключ будет всегда, например, 16 символов, вне зависимости от длины имени пользователя. Оба варианта (и ваш и мой) имеют недостаток. Можно дизасемблировать программу, узнать ключ шифрования и написать генератор ключей.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко как при таком подходе установить дату окончания пробного периода или указать, что определённая функция программы активирована? Мой подход не странный, а вынужденный, т.к. требуется offline активация и + информация  должна быть зашифрована в ключе.

Comment: @AntonShchyrov дату окончания лицензии, тип лицензии, флаги "фич" - включено/выключено и т.д..

Comment: Передавайте эту информацию в открытом виде (и пользователю будет интересно) и добавляйте хеш сообщения. В программе хешируете опять и сравниваете хеши

Comment: @AntonShchyrov на сколько я понимаю, Ваше предложение похоже на файл лицензии.

Comment: XelaNimed, если офлайн активация с километровым ключем, то стоит использовать асиметричное шифрование. Тогда если дизасемблируют программу, то не смогут написать генератор ключей. Если это волнует не сильно, то передавать эту информацию в открытом виде и использовать в качестве соли или части тайной строки при хешировании.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко для .Net в принципе нет 100% способа защиты. А насчёт последнего, вообще не уверен, что Вас понял. "Соль", либо "часть тайной строки" для хеширования предполагает, что она будет одинаковая при кодировании/декодировании информации. Каким-же образом я буду проверять на одной и той-же программе (читай с одинаковой "солью") корректность разной информации?

Comment: А в чем принципиальное отличие?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov программный код у всех одинаков, различается лишь ключ лицензии и имя его владельца. Исходя из этого, каким образом мне получить информацию о количестве лицензий, дате окончания пробной версии и т.д. используя асимметричное шифрование или хэширование? Я не против, но не знаю... Как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Благодаря комментариям [tym32167](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179763) и [Zergatul](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/9784) проблема была решена, а следующие методы были изменёны для работы со строками любой длины:

```cs
static string GenerateUID(byte[] bytes)
{
    string[] arr = new string[bytes.Length / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = BASE36.Encode(BitConverter.ToUInt64(bytes, 8 * i));
    }
    return string.Join("-", arr);
}

static byte[] GetUIDInBytes(string UID)
{
    string[] ids = UID.Split('-');
    byte[] val = new byte[ids.Length * 8];
    for(int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
    {
        Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(BASE36.Decode(ids[i])), 0, val, 8 * i, 8);
    }
    return val;
}
```

Буду рад любым конструктивным замечаниям и предложениям!

P.S.: как и прежде, с исправленным и рабочим кодом можно "поиграться" [здесь](https://repl.it/@XelaNimed/SimpleLicInfo).